# Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Installer Project template how to prompt the end user to restart their PC once installation is complete?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer

I need to prompt users to restart their PC after installing a program.  I have created a MSI installer using the Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Installer Project template.

There is no option in the project properties to prompt for restart once the installation is complete, and I have searched high and low on the web but am unable to find a way to configure the installer project to do this.

Is there no option I can configure for this in the installer project?
Do I have to write some code for a Custom Action to do it?

I have to do a reboot after install, as the software will be running in a corporate environment, and will run on machines that do not have admin rights.  The software adds a reg entry that enables it to automatically start with windows.  I have found that when I start the software from installer upon successful completion, it does not have access to certain paths in the user dir, that it does have access to when it starts with windows.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows will reboot the PC if it's actually required for the installation to complete, so it may be worth explaining why you need the reboot. For example if it's needed to start a service just start it yourself in an installer class override.

The simplest way to do this is to open the MSI file with an MSI editor such as Orca, go to the InstallExecuteSequence table and add a new row, with the Action ScheduleReboot (case-sensitive) just after CostFinalize (although the location isn't too important) with a condition of Not Installed.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371527(v=vs.85).aspx

That'll give you the standard message asking for the reboot.  If you must be more aggressive, use the ForceReboot action instead after InstallFinalize.

The condions need to be chosen wisely otherwise you'll get a reboot on every action, such as repair and uninstall.

Visual Studio setup projects have limited functionality when compared with other tools such as InstallShield, WiX, Advanced Installer and so on. That's why this isn't an option in the IDE.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have updated the question with detail on why the need to reboot.  Hard to believe that you have to use a third party product for this and there is not just a simple config option in the VS Project Template...  I guess they wanna steer developers away from forcing their users to reboot, but at this point I don't have another option.

Comment: Orca is in the Windows SDK Kit. VS setup projects are "simple" but the price you pay is that you don't get all the Windows Installer functionality.

Comment: If that executable you run is fired off from a custom action and does not have access to some paths you may be running it deferred, which will run it with the system account.